# What is the data holding limit of user defined table types while passing them to stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, user-defined-types, user-defined-data-types

I was trying to search it everywhere but could not find what is the limit of the data that I can pass in user defined table types to stored procedure.

Also, is it a good practice to pass data like this in stored procedure? Specially if we want to pass some good amount of data.

Comment: There isn't an upper limit, though if you are inserting millions of rows into a table type then you are very likely to get poor performance, as SQL Server makes certain assumptions about row counts with table type variables/parameters, and you'll be better off using a physical table.

Comment: @Larnu - Okay, so it will just be performance issues but it will still work, right? And for thousands of rows it should work fine?

Comment: A 1,000 or so rows will likely be fine (best way it to test), but it's best to test. Like i mentioned SQL Server makes assumptions on how many rows; it used to assume there was only a **single** row in them but I recall that newer versions assume higher than that (I can't recall is it's 100 or 1,000).